# WSO2 ESB - Switch mediator, condition with number

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm working on an API and i would like to add a condition "higher than" like this :

```
<switch source="$ctx:myValue">
<case regex="$ctx:myValue > 1000">
...
</case>
<default/>
</switch>
```

Do you have any idea how to do this condition ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered my question by myself.

I used a script mediator like this :

```
 <script language ="js">
            <![CDATA[
            var nbResultatJS = mc.getProperty('nbMessage');
            var isSuperiorJS = 0;
            if(nbResultatJS > 1000){
                isSuperiorJS = 1;
            }
            mc.setProperty('isSuperior', isSuperiorJS);
            
            ]]>
            </script>
            <log level="custom">
                        <property name="MSG" expression="$ctx:isSuperior"/>
                    </log>
            
            <switch source="$ctx:isSuperior">
                <case regex="1.0">
                ...
                </case> </switch>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the Filter mediator.

```
<filter xpath="get-property('myValue') > 1000">
   <then>
     ... do something
   </then>
   <else>
      ... do something else
   </else>
</filter>
```

Or, in case of the switch mediator,  a simple regex for a value of 1000 or larger would be

```
[1-9][0-9]{3,}
```

However more specific requirements would be call for more complex regular expressions. So in the end a Filter mediator is probably your best bet in this case.